# Handling "raw data" in Node.js and passing on the data in a Node Express endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream, axios

I'm making an API call to get a file using axios:

```
   async function getData() {
    const config = {}; // { responseType: 'stream'};
    const { data } = await axios.get(URL, config);

    console.log(data);
    return data;
   }
```

When I attempt to print the result of my HTTP request, I get a bunch of nonsense (looks like some type of raw data) - Snapshot here:

```
...
�nG��p���1�l�ՓA�zw:/F�  �@ǇW>
��⟿_��̠����������=�|�d�s_���A�GԢ������ 
...
```

I want to pass on this data (an image or video file) to whoever is reaching my Node Express server's endpoint - How am I supposed to do that? I've read something about using a Stream and then pipe it into the response.

```
   router.get("/file", async(res,res) => {
       const file = await getFile();

       //const stream = fs.createReadStream(file)
       //res.pipe(stream)
   })
```

My problem is however I don't know how to deal with the data I get back from the API in the first place. I have tried changing the `responseType` of axios to `stream`(default:`json`) which gives me back an object but not sure how to handle it either.

Edit - Attempt 1:

```
 async function getData() {
    const config = { responseType: 'stream'};
    const { data } = await axios.get(URL, config);

    console.log(data);
    return data;
   }

   router.get("/file", async(res,res) => {
       const file = await getFile();

       file.pipe(res);
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `responseType` being stream, axios resolves to a response object whose `data` property is a stream, which you can pipe to the response:

```
 const file = await getFile();
 file.data.pipe(/*to*/ res);
```

Comment: Edited my attempt into the question - I got an error trying to pipe it

Comment: It is indeed different, that's my bad. Apologies